# python pptx, bullet points, how to change bullet symbol to numbers

Tags: python, powerpoint

In python pptx module,

```
p = frame.add_paragraph()
p.text = 'text1'
p = frame.add_paragraph()
p.text = 'text2'
```

will generate

- Text1
- Text2

How can I switch to a numbered list?

1. text1
2. text2

Thanks.

Comment: What package you are using?

Comment: Hi, pptx (in the title) is actually a python package. I changed the content to be clear.

Comment: If you use the ipython notebook, you can try to do a presentation inside it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There's not yet an option to change bullet style directly in python-pptx.

However, if you create a slide layout having a numbered bullet placeholder in the 'starting-point/template' deck you start out with, you can use that layout to create the slide you want.

You'll need to understand this bit in the documentation about how `python-pptx` loads presentations:
http://python-pptx.readthedocs.org/en/latest/user/presentations.html

And you'll need to create and use one of your own rather than use the default built-in 'template'.

Comment: Thanks @scanny. Yes, I do have my own template. Sometimes I want bullets on level 0 and numbers on level 1. Of course I can create one slide like this in master and use that. Would be nice to be able to switch around though, when I want a random mix of bullets and numbers.

Comment: There are a couple open feature requests on the GitHub issue tracker here if you want to give one (or both:) of them a +1 and perhaps elaborate them with the behaviors you're looking for: https://github.com/scanny/python-pptx/issues?q=is%3Aissue+is%3Aopen+bullet